# Display a component next to mouseposition

Tags: delphi

This is for learning sake ....

I am trying do display a component (label) there, where I click with my right mouse button.

How can I move the control around the form where I right click with the mouse?

Comment: A control is heavyweight way to draw text. Why not just paint text? Other than that, in what are you stuck? What do you know how to do already?

Comment: Is this for designtime or runtime usage? And does of may the (type of) control under the mouse cursor have influence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign an `OnMouseUp` event handler to the Form and set the control's `Left` and `Top` properties to the provided X-Y coordinates, which are relative to the Form's client area:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbRight then
  begin
    Label1.Left := X;
    Label1.Top := Y;
  end;
end;
```

If the control is not an immediate child of the Form itself, but is instead a child of another control, such as a `TPanel`, then assign the `OnMouseUp` event handler to the Parent control instead.